# Confusion over $\not\equiv$ and $\neq$ when applying boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Here $k, A_1, A_2$ are constants

Although $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx \not\equiv 0$, $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx$ can equal zero at certain values of $x$

For example if $A_1=1, A_2=1, k=1$ then

cos$x$+sin$x=0$ at $x=-\pi/4$, so is the conclusion of this solution incorrect? i.e

Is the solution:

$w^2=gk$tanh$(kh)$ $\cup$ $A_1$cos$kx+A_2$sin$kx=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation needs to hold for every $x$. For every choice of $A_1, A_2$ not both vanishing, there exists some $x$ such that $A_1 \cos kx + A_2 \sin kx \neq 0$. Therefore the other factor must be zero there.

Since the other factor is independent of $x$, that's all we get, and all we need.

Comment: I don't understand why this equation must hold for every $x$. $-w^2\zeta(x,y)+g\zeta_y(x,y)=0$ on $y=0$ is  $-w^2\zeta(x,0)+g\zeta_y(x,0)=0$, which is a function of $x$. So why don't I now just look for points where this function of $x$ ($f(x)$) $=0$?

Comment: A boundary condition says that a certain equation must hold "for all points on the boundary". The boundary is "for every $(x,y)$ such that $y = 0$." This is vastly different from (your interpretation of) "finding points $(x,y)$ on the boundary where a certain equation holds". Or, equivalently, the statement "$-w^2 \zeta(x,y) + g \zeta_y(x,y) = 0$ on $y = 0$" _means_ "defining the function of $x$ by $\tilde{\zeta}(x) = -w^2 \zeta(x,0) + g\zeta_y(x,0)$, it must be that $\tilde{\zeta}(x) \equiv 0$." The reason that you don't see $\equiv$ used in the first statement is that the equation,

Comment: as written, is not an identity: it is only an identity if you take away the $y$ dependence by fixing $y = 0$. Alternatively and equivalently, you can read the statement to mean that "the solution set of $-w^2\zeta(x,y) + g\zeta_y(x,y) = 0$ must include $\{y = 0\}$."